# Installing texlive 2015 on linux using yum

Tags: texlive

I was wondering how I can upgrade my texlive 2013 (installed via `yum`) to texlive 2015.  It is very bizarre that `yum update` does not automatically upgrade texlive to 2015 ...

Comment: You don't mention which Linux you are using. But if your Linux distribution provided you with text live 2013, then it is highly unlikely they will also provide text live 2015 for the same version of that Linux distribution. I usually recommend using the socalled TUG texlive instead, then you also get access to tlmgr (the update manager) which is often left out on the various Linux distributions

Comment: I suggest the vanilla install with `install-tl`

Comment: @TeXnician Done & a link re. (3) which is the only really different bit.

Answer (score 1):

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu concerns `apt`-based systems, but you can adapt the answers there to `yum` and whichever distro you are using. There are 3 key steps:

1. remove the `yum` packaged TeX Live;
2. install upstream's TeX Live;
3. install a 'dummy' package using `yum` so that you can install TeX-dependent software without `yum` reinstalling its version.

(1) and (2) are straightforward. (3) is addressed in my answer to [How to fool yum when installing texlive with tlmgr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309272/how-to-fool-yum-when-installing-texlive-with-tlmgr?rq=1) Obviously, change the year if you are installing a TeX Live edition that differs from the one I use in the example. (Although a dummy package may continue to work, depending on the way your distro names its repackaged TeX Live.)